# Array from blob converting to bitmap and using in listView

Tags: android, arrays, listview, bitmap

I want to save image to `sqlLite` and read it and display in `listview`
saving is working correctly (using `blob`)
for example my image is `R.drawable.icon`  after saving I have an `byte[]`
I used it in this way

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
holder.img.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

it works fine but my listview is working slowly now.
I have tried to set like this (using image not the array)

```
holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

and this works fine... 
so when I am using `bitmaps` it becomes slow... any ideas how to show array to `imageView`?

NOTICE I have `android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want/need to use sqlite for this task?

Comment: I want to store pictures to my database (not in sdcard)

Comment: Slowly because your app need more time to decode array to bitmap in memory and still loop on every image from sqlite blob. When you set ImageResource from drawable then image have ready in memory don't need more time to decode.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works slowly because every time your image becomes visible the bytearray gets decoded. That consumes memory and time. When you set the  image like this `holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);` it simply loads the image from your drawable folder which doesnt consume memory. What you should try is creating a new thread (maybe using AsyncTask) that loads your images in the background. This way you can scroll through your list and the images will be loaded in the background while youre scrolling.